# How to null check List in Robot FrameWork

Tags: robotframework

```
    ${rowcount}=    Keyword1    Book1.xlsx    0
    ${length}=    Set Variable    ${rowcount}
    ${i}    Set Variable    1
   :FOR    ${rowvalue}    IN RANGE    ${rowcount}
   \    @{columnlist}=    Keyword2    ${rowvalue}
```

`Keyword2` is returning List of data. I want to check whether it is returning `Empty` List. Please help me with this?

Answer (score 7):

The BuiltIn library has keywords [Should be empty](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Should%20Be%20Empty) and [Should not be empty](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Should%20Not%20Be%20Empty) which can be used to validate the length of a list.

```
Should Be Empty      ${columnlist}

Should Not Be Empty  ${columnlist}
```

Comment: If `${columnlist}` is not empty then I have to execute keyword below it. Is it possible using `If statement`?

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone else comes here looking for an answer which also addresses:

> If ${columnlist} is not empty then I have to execute keyword below it. Is it possible using If statement? – Orsu Suni Jun 12 '17 at 4:44

Either one of these options should help (NOTE: only used within RIDE, I imagine they will work for others as well):

1. ${len}  Get Length   ${columnlist} ---- will return zero if list is empty, you can then use ${len} in your conditional.
2. '@{columnlist}' == '@{EMPTY}' ---- should return true if list is empty, although so far I have only used it with RUN KEYWORD IF.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could run the following keyword:

```
${isEmpty}    Run Keyword And Return Status    Should Be Empty      ${columnlist}
```

Then you get a boolean value in `${isEmpty}` with whether the list is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

Statements/conditions in Robot are a bit confusing in my opinion. Previous suggestion 2. doesn't work for me. I'm using: Robot Framework 3.1.2 (Python 3.4.1 on win32)

I obtain expected solution:

```
*** Test Cases ***
TC1
    ${marker_files}  Create List  dummy3  dummy4  dummy5
    Run keyword unless  ${marker_files} == @{EMPTY}  Operation on list 
    marker_files=${marker_files}

tc2
    ${marker_files}  Create List  @{EMPTY}
    Run keyword unless  ${marker_files} == @{EMPTY}  Operation on list  
    marker_files=${marker_files}

*** Keywords ***
Operation on list
    [Arguments]  ${marker_files}=def
    log to console  \ndo something on list
```